# Non-degenerate operator with determinant zero. Is it possible?

Tags: operator-algebras

Let us consider the 2x2 matrix filled with 1s. Its eigenvalues are 0 and 2, so it is non-degenerate, but its determinant is zero, i.e. it is not invertible. What's going on?

Comment: There is no contradiction. It's degenerate because it is not invertible. Why would having 2 eigenvalues make an operator non-degenerate?

Comment: "Non-degenerate" has two meanings and you are conflating them (and so is the other commenter). One of them means the matrix is invertible and the other means it has distinct eigenvalues. These conditions are not equivalent and this is a counterexample.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Now I see that! Thank you